# HashMap<HashMap<Integer, Integer>, String> in JSP access

Tags: java, jsp, hashmap

```
HashMap<HashMap<Integer, Integer>, String> myMap = new HashMap<HashMap<Integer, Integer>, String>();

HashMap<Integer, Integer> mmm = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
mmm.put(1, 2);
myMap.put(mmm, "la");

mmm = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
mmm.put(2, 3);
myMap.put(mmm, "ololo");
```

How to get access to myMap from JSP page by key?
I need something like

```
<td>${myMap[2][3]}</td>
```

to print

```
<td>ololo</td>
```

Comment: Why are you using HashMap as a key to single value? Are you sure that it is what you wanted?

Comment: There is simply example

Answer (score 0):

You need to create map like mmm to access value from myMap. Chek following code of jsp.

```
    <%  HashMap<Integer, Integer> mmm1 = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
mmm1.put(2, 3);
%>
<td><%=(myMap.get(mmm1)) %></td>
```

Comment: I need like this, but without <% tags, only JSP

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:forEach var="outEntry" items="${myMap}">
  <c:forEach var="inEntry" items="${outEntry.key}">
    <c:if test="${inEntry.key== 2 && inEntry.value==3}">
         <td><c:out value="${outEntry.value}"/></td>
     </c:if>
  </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

You can retrieve using JSTL.

Comment: I need not foreach, I need direct access by key

Comment: @Artik I dont think its possible to get map by using key in JSTL without iteration.